# How to make sure variable scope is maintained in this loop

Tags: javascript, scope, dom-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

I have a loop with an `image.onload` call like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  var item = array[i]
    , image = new Image();

  image.onload = function(){
    // do something with 'item'
  }
  image.src = url;
}
```

Because I do not know when the `onload` function is being triggered, I believe that `item` is getting overwritten. How do I make sure that each `onload` function is triggered with the `item` variable referencing the data that it does at the time the function is bound to the `onload` event?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
image.onload = function(item){
    return function(){
      // do something with 'item'
    }(item);
};
```

What you want to do is to create "scope" so that when the event function is called, the [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) brings the value you want with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use an IIFE to return a function that uses the current item

```
  image.onload = (function(param){
    return function(){
    //do something with 'param'
    }
  })(item);
```